# Typescript Allow Users to Add Additional Properties

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make a component that really only expects the options to be passed in to at least have 2 properties. The user can pass in more properties if they want so when they do a custom component they could have more properties to use. Here is the bare minimial of what I expect.

```js
{
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

But the user could passing in the following:

```js
{
  id: number;
  name: string;
  disabled: boolean;
  icon: string;
  ....
}
```

So I am not sure how to build the interface.

Here is the interface I created

```
interface OptionProp {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

So in my main component interface I have

```
interface TypeComponent {
  options: OptionProp[] | any;
}
```

I think there has to be better way than using that `any`?

Answer (score 2):

It will come down to what you're ultimately trying to achieve, but you could potentially use generics with type constraints to achieve this.

As an [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgApTbrIDeAUMssACYBcyIArgLYBG0A3BQ3MxPQGcwUUAHMuAXzJlQkWIhQAVAJ7oIAYWzN0uCOAA8i5BAAekENQFpMOfIXQA+UtyJZcA+ooDaAXUnSYRhAENxBkamwAZS0IMAALMUNjMz1La1CCIgcACigIAEdGCCFPVQ0tHRA9MEMHAEpnSjzC4rAAOldbATaYbCgAUUQ47OxkAF4nBHdsABsINpnsURG2mgAaZGw2kF4IOrr-MgjovnixbPJKTvd6L0vKKjpkAEY17kodvnoAcgApbDiIG+bwe4WAAjgrDmT3gMwEEBBD2AUxA9CYMxm3AkPjIEgOZCAA):

```
interface OptionProp {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface TypeComponent<T extends OptionProp> {
  options: T[];
}

function doSomething<T extends OptionProp>(request: TypeComponent<T>) {
  request.options.forEach(o => console.log(o.id, o.name));
}

doSomething({
  options: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'John',
    disabled: false,
    icon: null
  }]
});
```

The `extends` constraint on `TypeComponent<T>` means that the type being used must extend `OptionProp` and can have any additional properties you would like to apply. `doSomething` will now happily take any request that has `options` that extends from `OptionProp`.

---

Another option is to use an indexed signature. [Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgApTbrIDeAUMssACYBcyIArgLYBG0A3BQ3MxPQGcwUUAHMulANoBrCAE9BwsQF16cEHK4BfMmVCRYiFABU56CAGFszdLgjhS3IllwD6GF-kLpJy7bphGEARPZGpsAGVrCDAACzEACigIAEdGCCF6U3MrGztwAEpHSmS0jLAAOmccEAEKmGwoAFFEWITsZABeAD5kBFdsABsICsHsUXaKmgAaZGwKkF4IAoL-MnCovjjE8kpq13pJXcoqOmQARmnuSkW+egByAClsWJB7q5Ow4AE4VmGz+CDAQQD4nYD9ED0JiDQbcLTKMhaVZkIA):

```
interface OptionProp {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  [key: string]: any;
}

interface TypeComponent {
  options: OptionProp[];
}

function doSomething(request: TypeComponent) {
  request.options.forEach(o => console.log(o.id, o.name));
}

doSomething({
  options: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'John',
    disabled: false,
    icon: null
  }]
});
```

This says that in addition to `id`, and `name`, `OptionProp` can contain any object `key` of type `any`.

---

Generics will allow you to be more explicit about the types that are used in other functions, while the indexed signature is more relaxed/loose about types that you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can set optional properties like this:

```
interface TypeComponent {
  options: OptionProp[];
  disabled?: boolean;
  icon?: string;
}
```

Comment: I do not know what someone is going to pass in that is extra, They could pass in 6 more props